# MVC4 View cannot find Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I;m try to call a simple action in my controller and receiving a 404. All other actions in the controller work fine; although they are called via AJAX.

**The Button**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RestartEmailService", "Email")" class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-envelope"></i> Restart Service</a>
```

**The controller action**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    protected ActionResult RestartEmailService()
    {
        try
        {
            svcController.Stop();
            svcController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            svcController.Start();

            return RedirectToAction("EmailAdminCenter");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return JavaScript(UnHandledEx);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not called because it is `protected` not `public` so it is not visible, it should be **public**:

```
public ActionResult RestartEmailService()
{

}
```

Comment: That's both hilarious and embarrassing. Thanks Ehsan.